# How to Sort a SubList containing String and Int as string

Tags: python-3.x, list

I need to Sort the list according to the integer which are in form of string and list also contains stings alphabets.

```
   li = [['dr','3','mn'],['fs','1','a'],['2','rt',c]]
```

I need the output like:

```
   li = [['fs','1','a'],['2','rt',c],['dr','3','mn']]
```

or

```
   li = [[1,'fs','a'],[2,'rt',c],[3,'dr','mn']]
```

in any of the format like these.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code supposes the numbers are integers and in each list there's at least one number:

```
li = [['11','rt','c'],['dr','3','mn'],['fs','1','a'],['2','rt','c']]

def is_number(s):
    try:
        i = int(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

print([li[i[-1]] for i in sorted([[int(j), ii] for ii, i in enumerate(li) for j in i if is_number(j)])])
```

Prints:

```
[['fs', '1', 'a'], ['2', 'rt', 'c'], ['dr', '3', 'mn'], ['11', 'rt', 'c']]
```